# Are there any video tutorials for P4V?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have just moved to a team where they use P4V tool and Perforce. I used to work with SVN.

Are there any video tutorials for P4V tool explaining its principles, usage etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Perforce has lots of useful video tutorials, linked from http://perforce.com/product/multimedia_library

Comment: Great! Thanks! By the way, here is a site which explains the "Streams": http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=2948

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v-gs/index.html